# Check if a commit in a branch was cherry-picked into master

Tags: git, git-branch, cherry-pick

Let's suppose that we have two branches: `master` and `feature_branch`.

Is there a possibility to check if each commit to the `feature_branch` was cherry-picked into `master`?

Comment: The command is [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry). If you're tracking master and on feature_branch, that's it: `git cherry`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `git-log` together with the [`--cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-pick) and [`--right-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---right-only) options for that:

```bash
git log --cherry-pick --right-only master...feature_branch
```

This will return the commits in `feature_branch` that *do not* have an equivalent<sup>1</sup> commit in `master`.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---right-only):

> `--cherry-pick --right-only A...B` omits those commits from `B` which are in `A` or are patch-equivalent to a commit in `A`. In other words, this lists the `+` commits from `git cherry A B`.

If there's no output, it means that all the commits in `feature_branch` have been cherry-picked into `master`.

---

1. Where by [*equivalent*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry#_description), we mean a commit whose diff is equal ignoring whitespace and line numbers.